# condition on hql statements

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have som hql statements running every day like

```
drop table if exists table1;
create table table1 as 
select ....
from A;
```

But some times create table fails and then my original table is¨deleted without a new one is created

I would like to do this a smarter way
like this pseudo code

```
if ( create table table1_tmp as 
     select .... 
     from A; )
then (    drop table table1 ;
          rename table1_tmp to table1 ;
     )
```

Is it possible to do that in hql or do i have to at
pig, spark, python etc.

Comment: Why don't you use `INSERT OVERWRITE`?

Comment: thanks! why did i not think of that, Would you please make your suggestion an anwser so i can close the question

Answer (score 0):

[`INSERT OVERWRITE`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML) is the best fit for what you are trying to do.

You might want to keep an eye on your HDFS Trash folder because I think the underlying files always move to `/user/<username>/.Trash` when you perform an `INSERT OVERWRITE`